# adding third button to Navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have added two buttons to navigation controller one inplace of right button and left button, I want to add a third button just before the right button. How to do it?

```
 UIButton *logo_btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [logo_btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-57.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[logo_btn setFrame:CGRectMake(-2, 0, 47, 47)];

UIBarButtonItem *btnItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:logo_btn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnItem1;
```

This is how I have added one button at left.

Comment: Used this [link](http://osmorphis.blogspot.in/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html).You will get to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS 5 helps you at creating more than 2 barbuttons on the Navigation Bar

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:uibarbuttonInstance1, uibarbuttonInstance2, nil];
```

same for right buttons

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:uibarbuttonInstance1, uibarbuttonInstance2, nil];
```